# Logitech keyboard failing after Installing 14.04

Tags: logitech-unifying

I have a little problem with my Logitech K360 keyboard, the pc is a Intel NUC DN2820.
When I have it on the nightstand, it won't work and when I have it in the bed it works fine, there is talk about 15cm difference.

With hardly works I would say that it is not catching what I type.
It happened after I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and on Windows it worked.
I'm using Solaar, and it says that my mouse and keyboard has low power when I boot up.
It's a really annoying problem, what can I do?

Comment: Sorry for bad grammar and sentences, I was posting this in norwegian and I just translated in google and changed a little :)

Comment: Can you find anything in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/` that looks like `mouse`, `keyboard` and/or `Logitech`?

Comment: I'll try it later :) I really hope I'm gonna fix this

Comment: I tried the command, and this is what came up; bash /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/: is a directory

Comment: Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Okey, I took it in terminal :P I'll take it later :) I hope it's gonna work sometime

Comment: I didn`t find anything :( Nothing at all

Comment: Too bad!  Now I'm going to use a cannon to kill a mosquito! (Answer coming up!)

Comment: Huh, what did you mean? :P xD

Comment: "To kill a mosquito with a cannon" means to use extreme force to do something very simple... (maximum comments reached: you should delete some comments again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no specific settings in your power management directory for Logitech keyboard and mouse, there is only one thing you can do:  turn off all power management settings instead of just the power management settings for Logitech!

1. Go to your BIOS and turn off all power management settings
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
   ```

Now it should work from much further away...

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Uhm, I dont think I got any power mangegement on my Visual BIOS, havent seen anything

Comment: You answered too quickly to be able to reboot and go over all the settings in your BIOS!  Try again!  :P ;-)

Comment: Haha, I know, I said that I don`t know that I have anything, but I`ll look! :)

Comment: WTF, I can`t access BIOS -.-
I turned on Fast Boot and it`s gonna disable if I hold the power button in and 3 short beeps come, it did but it didn`t work....

Comment: I can't help you with that!  Download the manual for your hardware and have a look in there!

Comment: Nah, It works now. Just typed the command in terminal, rebooted and it work :) Thanks :)))

Comment: It don't work... And I can't even access BIOS

Comment: The only additional help I can give you now is to try brand new batteries...  No more ideas! (except you downloading the BIOS manual for your machine / chipset, but I've already told you that)

Comment: There are no drivers for the NUC to Ubuntu. But I'll try! I find it very weird, the K360 is under 3 weeks...